# NavigationBar indicatorColor blips when changing the NavigationDestination

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

I am implementing **`NavigationBar`** widget as `bottomNavigationBar:` inside **Scaffold**. I have three **`NavigationDestination`** items in the Navigation Bar.

Two of the items has **colorful** `indicatorColor:` and one of them is **transparent**. So, I added a condition based on the **index** of the items to handle the color.

However When the item with **transparent** indicatorColor is selected and any of the items with **colorful** indicatorColor is tapped on there is a blip of Color on the **transparent** item like the video below:

[Demo Video](https://imgur.com/a/0yIJKCe)

I am using **`go_router`** for route management. The **navigationShell** in the `body:` section comes from **go_router**

Here is my code snippet:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key, required this.navigationShell})
      : super(key: key ?? const ValueKey('ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation'));

  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: navigationShell,
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
          height: 80.h,
          selectedIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
          indicatorColor: navigationShell.currentIndex == 0
              ? Colors.transparent
              : AppColors.bottomNavIconGreen,
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          destinations: [
            NavigationDestination(
                label: 'Chat',
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
                  size: 24.h,
                )),
            NavigationDestination(
                label: 'History',
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.access_time,
                  size: 24.h,
                )),
            NavigationDestination(
                label: 'Account',
                icon: Icon(
                  CupertinoIcons.person_crop_circle,
                  size: 24.h,
                )),
          ],
          onDestinationSelected: (index) {
            index != 0
                ? navigationShell.goBranch(
                    index,
                    initialLocation: index == navigationShell.currentIndex,
                  )
                : context.pushNamed('chat');
          }
         ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

*** And also I want to make the `label:` of the selected **NavigationDestination** item bold.

I really would appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

**NavigationBar** has a default `animationDuartion:` of 500 milliseconds

```
animationDuration: Duration.zero
```

Making animation duration to zero solved my issue.